# Как в боте отредактировать фото несколько раз подряд

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Пишу сейчас Телеграм бота и столкнулась с проблемой, что не получается во второй раз изменить сообщение. Такое ощущение, что как-то меняется message_id.. Удивительно, что проблема у меня возникла именно с edit_message_media, а вот edit_message_text таких ошибок мне раньше не выдавал.

```
bot.edit_message_media(
    chat_id=player_id,
    message_id=callback_query.message.message_id,
    media=types.InputMediaPhoto(combined_image_io)

)


bot.edit_message_media(
    chat_id=player_id,
    message_id=callback_query.message.message_id,
    media=types.InputMediaPhoto(combined_image_io),
    reply_markup=markup
)
```

Первый edit_message_media выполняется, а вот на втором всё ломается. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: А почему markup меняется только во втором? Markup, конечно, [можно менять](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib/docs/classtd_1_1td__api_1_1edit_message_media.html), но возможно с ним затык. Если же, как вы предположили, проблема с `message_id`, можно его сохранить и переиспользовать `message_id = callback_query.message.message_id`, да и в консоль для дебага полезно вывести.